# iOS. Could I made custom view for UIScrollView in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have a UIViewController, there is a "static" part in the View, and the scrolling part (UIScrollView). I know that I must add some View to the UIScrollView.

It's possible to make this View in code only, but I want to make UIView that contains some separated text with different size and colour, for this I will use Labels.

It's will a little bigger that a standard fullscreen UIView, so my question is: is it possible to make a UIView that will be bigger than standard iPhone screen in the Xcode, add all what I want from the objects pallet and then use it in the UIScrollView? If so, how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a UIView (self.view) of lets say 320x480
2. Add a scrollView in (self.view) of size (320x480)
3. Create a new UIView (dataView) of size (320x1200(any height you
   want))
4. add step3 View(dataView) in the scrollView (step2 view)
5. set the contentsize of the ScrollView to (320x1200)

**becareful set the contentsize to 320x1200 not the scrollView frame size**

Comment: Oh, nice, I'll try this right now, and ask you some questions if it appear :)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30636/ios-problems-discussion join it for chat